# In ruby, is there a way to tell a class to inherit variables/methods from outside binding?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Here's a simple example:

```
def abc
    puts 'abc'
end

class Foo
    def self.bar
        abc
    end
end

Foo.bar
```

This breaks because `abc` is undefined inside `Foo.bar`. Is there a way to tell the class to "inherit" the local binding to make the above work? I'm basically trying to create a simple namespace for the "bar" method.

My first attempt was to subclass from the current eigenclass (`class Foo < (class << self; self; end)`) but you can't subclass a virtual class. Also, while I could explicitly pass in the binding and use eval inside, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is that code running at the top level, or is there some context you're leaving out? If it's top-level code, there should be no error, and that should print 'abc'. See this question and answer for a bit of why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761148/where-are-methods-defined-at-the-ruby-top-level

Comment: @duelinmarkers, you're right. I am running within a context, and thought this would be a minimal case, but it's different. Since I was confused, I'm going to flag this question for deletion.

Comment: @Ben I found your question interesting, replicated the code in IRB, and found, like @duelin that there is no error.  If it does fail in the context, perhaps instead of deleting it, you could provide some context?
`$ irb
1.9.3p286 :001 > def abc
1.9.3p286 :002?>   puts 'abc'
1.9.3p286 :003?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p286 :004 > class Fee
1.9.3p286 :005?>   def self.bar
1.9.3p286 :006?>     abc
1.9.3p286 :007?>     end
1.9.3p286 :008?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p286 :009 > Fee.bar
abc
 => nil `

Comment: @Dmitri, the issue is much more complex than this, it would be a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This breaks because `abc` is undefined inside `Foo.bar`.

No, it doesn't. `abc` is implicitly defined as a private instance method of `Object` and since a class IS-A `Object`, you can call it just fine. The code you posted should work as-is, and indeed *does* work for me.

Comment: Thank you. Someone pointed this out in the comments hours ago, right after I posted the question, and I was hoping someone would actually post this as answer so I could give them the checkmark :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

but I generally dont advice to do it myself though

```
def abc
    puts 'abc'
end

class Foo
    def self.bar
        eval("abc",TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
    end
end

Foo.bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a simple namespace, can you use a module?

```
def abc
  puts 'abc'
end

module Foo
  def self.bar
    abc
  end
end

Foo.bar #=> abc
```