# Why are global methods allowed to be defined outside of a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object

I read this:

> Let’s start with a simple Ruby program. We’ll write a method that
>   returns a cheery, personalized greeting.
>
> ```
> def say_goodnight(name)
>     result = "Goodnight, " + name
>     return result
> end
> ```

My understanding is that a method is a function or subroutine that is defined in a class, which can be associated to a class (class method) or to an object (instance method).

Then, how can that be a method if it was not defined within a class?

Comment: Recall that methods return the last value calculated. For that reason, this method would normally be written `def say_goodnight(name); "Goodnight, " + name; end`. Also, you'd often see the second line written, `"Goodnight, #{ name }"` or `"Goodnight, %s" % name`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you define a function in Ruby at the global scope in this way, it technically becomes a `private` method of the `Object` class, which is the base class that everything inherits from in Ruby. [*Everything* in Ruby is an object](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/), so it is indeed true that you have defined a method.

```
def say_goodnight(name)
    result = "Goodnight, " + name
    return result
end

Object.private_methods.include? :say_goodnight
=> true
```

Because it is defined as a method with `private` visibility on `Object`, it can only be called inside objects of the class on which it's defined or subclasses. So why does it appear to be available globally?

Basically, the Ruby program itself defines an instance of `Object` called `main`, which serves as the top-level scope where your method was defined. So if you think of your program as running *inside* `main` (which is an `Object`) its private methods are available for use.

```
# In irb:
self
=> main
self.class
=> Object
self.private_methods.include? :say_goodnight
=> true
```

**Addendum:**
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766131/541091) which further explains how `main` is defined and implemented.

#### Update for Ruby >= 2.3

Noted in the comment thread, later versions of Ruby would define the method `Object#say_goodnight` in this example with `public` visibility rather than `private`. This behavior appears to have changed between Ruby 2.2.x and 2.3.x, but does not affect method exposure.

Comment: Being private has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: when I run these code in `irb` with ruby-2.6.5, the method is defined as public

Comment: @lfx_cool I can confirm that. I'll have to investigate when the change happened and update the answer accordingly