# To which object are top-level methods assigned in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby every method is assigned to an object (right?). Ruby provides a lot of "built in" methods and gives the ability to the user to create "user defined" methods.

Built in methods are all defined in a class like String, Integer, Array and so on. Built in methods are all invoked placing a dot after an object followed by the method call.

```
string = "example"
string = string.reverse
```

However, when I define a method with the syntax

```
def method_name (args)
   #body
end
```

to which object is this method assigned? And why when I have to call a method that I have defined I don't use the "dot syntax" but I just write its name and pass it some arguments without applying it to an object, like this:

```
method_name args
```

Comment: The key question (and half of the answer :)) is "_Where_ do you define this method?" In REPL session (irb/pry/...)?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that.
I have a file called example.rb and I'm defining a method there, I'm not using irb

Comment: If you are not defining methods within classes/modules you are defining them in a special top-level execution context. This context is in fact a special instance of `Object` called `main`. Any objects that you define this way are in fact defined on `Object`, so they become globally available. Convenient for sketchy things and hacking in REPL but try to avoid this in bigger contexts - will shoot your leg sooner or later.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27767534/477037 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1761148/477037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is top-level object in Ruby -- `main`

```
def method_name(args)
  # body
end
```

```
self
# => main

self.methods.grep(/method_name/)
# => [:method_name]
```

`main` is an instance of `Object`. Any methods defined in `main` become instance methods of `Object`

```
Object.private_instance_methods.grep(/method_name/)
# => [:method_name]
```

This makes them available everywhere (because all classes are descendants of `Object`), meaning that we can call the method without a receiver inside classes

For example

```
def foo
  puts "foo"
end

class X
  def y
    foo
  end
end

# will print foo
X.new.y

# will raise private method `foo' called for #<X:0x000055e406a0f060> (NoMethodError)
# to reproduce don't use irb, just usual file
X.new.foo
```

Read [more](https://bparanj.gitbooks.io/ruby-basics/content/the_main_object.html)

Comment: Can you clarify why "any methods defined in main become instance method of Object"?. I thought the only place where you could declare methods were inside of classes, not inside of an object. Hence, why can we declare a method inside of the main object?

Comment: @LorenzoZabot: "I thought the only place where you could declare methods were inside of classes" – This is not true. First of all, methods can be defined in *modules* as well (in fact, classes are a subtype of modules … kind of). Secondly, you are confusing where a method definition occurs *lexically*, i.e. where it appears in the *source code* with where the method is *defined*. The two are not always the same.

Answer (score 2):

> In Ruby every method is assigned to an object (right?)

Incorrect. In Ruby, methods are assigned to modules (including classes). When you call a method on an object, Ruby runtime searches for the method along the object's class's ancestor chain (the object's singleton class -> the object's class ->
the superclass -> superclass's superclass -> ... -> BasicObject). If the method is found, it is bound to the object and gets called, otherwise the Ruby runtime searches for a special method called `method_missing` and bind it to the current object and calls it.

> to which object is this method assigned?

It's assigned to the class `Object`, as a private instance method.

```rb
def foo
  :foo
end

Object.private_instance_methods.grep(/foo/)
#=> [:foo]
```

I guess Ruby does this in order to make top-level "functions" look global.

```rb
class A
  def self.a
    foo
  end

  def a
    foo
  end
end

A.a  #=> :foo
A.new.a  #=> :foo
```